# Why isn't the RewriteRule working on my Synology NAS hosted website?

Tags: .htaccess, web, synology, nas

Please can anyone tell me why the RewriteRule's aren't working on my website:
https://markbanf.synology.me/

If you click the links they show the 404 page. You have to add .php to actually view it.

My .htaccess file is set up as follows:-

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^experience/?$ experience.php
    RewriteRule ^development/?$ development.php
    RewriteRule ^portfolio/?$ portfolio.php

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This is a basic HTML and PHP website hosted on a Synology DS216 NAS. Server is Apache/2.4.54.

The exact same files work fine when hosted elsewhere: https://www.markbanf.co.uk/

Comment: Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled? Is mod_rewrite installed/enabled? Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper (that's only going to mask any errors). What is the URL you are requesting? Your rules are in the wrong order (although not the cause of your immediate problem). The regex in your 4th rule is also wrong (but again, not the cause of your immediate problem). (Is that 4th rule even reqd?)

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. I'm pretty sure the .htaccess itself is working or the custom 404 page wouldn't show. I have taken the <IfModule> wrapper out as suggested. I'm trying to click on the 'experience' link which is supposed to show the experience.php web page which is in the root of the website just like the home page (index.php).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed the following line at the start of my `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

(This is only necessary as my website is hosted on a NAS.)

Comment: I searched for hours on this problem as my `.htaccess`-files also stopped working after updating to Apache 2.4. This also works for me!
Can you provide a link where you found this solution? Why does this line help?

Comment: I got the answer from someone on Reddit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/13xlge6/any_idea_why_the_links_dont_work_on_my_nas_hosted/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3